# Email not getting via cron job

Tags: php, curl, cron

```
<?php
    mail('myemail@example.com', 'Test email', 'Test cron running');
    ?>
```

`test_email.php` have above code, when i run this file manually (via URL) then i received email but via cron job i am not getting email.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/test/public_html/bs/cron/test_email.php >> /home/test/public_html/test_email.log & 

* * * * * curl --silent -o /dev/null http://www.example.com/cron/test_email.php
```

I used both cron command but no result.
Can anyone guide me where is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
* * * * * php /home/test/public_html/bs/cron/test_email.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is working but not in your cron, it looks like your cron table is not aware of your changes

Did you try restarting it with

`sudo service cron restart`

or

`sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this command to run my cron job :

wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/cron/test_email.php

If you really stock in that situation , try calling the attention of support of the server that you were using.